# Disabling Alt Esc (Holding down) VB.NET | VB

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I have tried disabling <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> which has worked, when you tap it. I have found a little bug where when you hold it down it will spam it and bypass my program. I have tried intercepting alt and escape individually which is not possible.

Thanks!

Current code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Alt = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Or e.Alt = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And

```
    Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

**NOTE: THIS PROGRAM IS FOR LEGAL PURPOSES AND LEGAL PURPOSES ONLY!**

Comment: sorry - but when you tap what?

Comment: Alt+Escape. Thought it was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Alt-ESC is a Windows system shortcut, and will never be visible to a user program.